# Undefined methods in Ruby class

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, methods

I'm trying to write a Die class that takes in an array of labels for its sides, and I first just want to find the length of the sides (the length of the array that was passed in (in my example, I'm just passing in ['A', 'B', C']

If I pass in an empty array, I want to raise an ArgumentError. For some reason, when I use @labels.length, I get an error message saying: 
    undefined method `length=' for ["A", "B", "C"]:Array (NoMethodError)

I've tried using other common array methods, with the same result. Do I need to re-define the length method in my class?? Any help would be much appreciated! Here is my code.. I understand it's not really complete, but

```
class Die
def initialize(labels)
@labels = [].push(labels).flatten

 if @labels.length = 0
    raise ArgumentError.new ("You can't use an empty array!")
 end

def sides
@labels
end

def roll
 p rand(@labels[0]..@lables[labels.length-1])
end
end
end

die = Die.new(['A','B','C'])
p die.roll
```

Comment: BTW, what is `[].push(labels).flatten` supposed to do?

Comment: @BSeven It would seem to be an overcomplicated way to do `labels.dup`.

Comment: Read the error message carefully. What is the name of the method you are calling that doesn't exist? Hint: it's not `length`!

Comment: Turns out, you can't call rand on strings!! I used sample instead. With some other changes, it's all good now, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
 @labels.length = 0
```

should be

```
 @labels.length == 0
```

Comment: Ah, yes! But now I'm getting undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (No Method Error)